# Div size changes depending on whether I use "div" or "link_to"

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I created clickable divs for the navigation page on my website. If I follow the syntax of the first way, the div has the right width (60px) but if I do it the second way it's only 44px. I need to use the second way. Why are there differences in sizes?

EDIT: I just also noticed that there seems to be no spacing before and after the letters if I use the second way. Maybe something to do with padding..

**First way**

```
<div id="item_2", onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"> About </div>
```

**Second way**

```
<%= link_to "http://www.facebook.com", id:"item_2" do %> About <% end %>
```

**CSS**

```
#item_2 {
    width: 60px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: your browser has different default styles for a div and a link, they are likely affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with CSS, and as pointed out in the comments, will probably be caused by you having some default width for your `a` tag elsewhere in your CSS

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "About Us", "http://facebook.com", id: "item_2" %>

#item_2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px !important;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Something else you need to know is `div`'s and `a` tags work differently by default (`div` is a block and `a` is treated as a span). I've tried looking for references for this, and [this Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div) is the best I could find

Another thing is `id`styling does not replace `class` styling. It's just a way of specifically identifying elements. So you may have class styling (either on the `div` or `a` class), which will be taking precedence

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rich Peck. It still doesn't work for me though - the div appears smaller than the others ones although it should be 60px.